# SSL offloading with IIS and Ajp (isapi) Tomcat

Tags: ssl, iis, tomcat, ajp, isapi

I have java web application running on **tomcat** on a **Windows 2019 server**.
It runs fine on port 8180.

I have a **IIS** (10.0) running on the same server with **isapi_redirector** 1.2.48 configured.
Now I can access my tomcat application on port 80, and IIS happily handles the ajp connection to tomcat.

So far so good.

Now I need IIS to do **ssl offloading**, ie I want to access IIS on port 443, and still access my tomcat application behind using ajp (isapi_redirector).

I'm lost in MS / IIS jungle, which is not familiar to me... This https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/archive/blogs/friis/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world-apps did not get me to a working solution, and ajp is another element in the mix that I'm unsure about.

Any pointer on how to do that ?